# How can I avoid traversing into an endlessly recursive directory link?

Tags: windows, recursion, filesystems

I have some functionality that traverses the filesystem recursively using `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()`.  This works fine, but the problem is that on occasion it comes across some kind of recursive link.  For example, `C:\foo\bar` links to `C:\foo`.  Most of these links are implemented with reparse points, so it is enough to avoid traversing into a folder with the `FILE_FLAG_REPARSE_POINT` attribute set.  However, on rare occasions one of these links will NOT have that flag set and thus the code gets stuck in an endless loop until the stack is exhausted.

My question is how can I detect these links in order to avoid endlessly traversing into them?

Unfortunately I do not have access to an environment that reproduces the problem so I can't gather any more information; all I have to go on are some crash dumps from Windows Error Reporting.  I have seen these non-reparse links on local (NTFS) filesystems, and possibly also on remote (SMB) file systems but I'm not 100% on that.

**EDIT**: More details from one of the dumps.

In one case the problem folder is `C:\users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Application Data`.  Here the `Application Data` part repeats over 700 times, and the total length of the path is 12K characters (24k bytes).  Due to local variables the stack is exhausted well before the 32K limit is reached.  This is a Windows 7 machine and the filesystem is NTFS, so normally `Application Data` is a junction to `AppData\Local`.  However, my code is not detecting this particular folder as a junction.  In the logs I can see it is detecting other junctions, so this leads me to believe it is an environmental issue.

Comment: Most implementations will check for the `FILE_FLAG_REPARSE_POINT` flag and skip that directory.

Comment: Perhaps this only happens when the file system is corrupt?

Comment: Do you have enough information to tell whether the directory name (not the full path, just the name) is repeating itself?

Comment: Also, can you tell whether the apparent path is getting very long?  I'm puzzled that the stack would become exhausted before the maximum path length was reached.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I don't imagine the filesystem would be corrupt as these instances occurred on production systems, but I don't know for sure.  Yes, it is only the directory name that repeats.  For example, `C:\AAA\BBB\CCC\CCC\CCC\......`.  We are using the syntax to allow for extended path lengths, but the point at which it starts repeating is not anywhere close to MAX_PATH.  In one case it happened at a top-level directory (e.g. `C:\AAA\AAA\AAA\...`).

Comment: Even using the `\\?\` prefix there is still a maximum path length of only about 32K wide characters.  If the process is running out of stack space before hitting this limit, then the problem might not be being (directly) caused by recursive links at all; there might just be a lot of very deeply nested directories, probably as the result of a previous attempt to copy a directory with a recursive link.  It sounds as if you need to refactor your code to limit the use of recursion.

Comment: If so, you can reproduce this easily enough, just write a short program to create deeply nested directories (`C:\AAA\AAA\...`) up to the 32K limit.

Comment: @HarryJohnston:  I have not explicitly looked at the length of the path, but I would guess it's not anywhere close to 32K.  Still, I will take another look at the dumps I have to verify.  The code is crashing due to stack exhaustion, most of which is due to local variables.  I never considered the possibility that it could be actual nested directories instead of funky recursive links.  I'll keep that in mind when I see more reports of this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have some way of getting the real path? If so you can have a structure of visited real paths so that it's checked before recursively following the directory.

The easiest to implement would be a hash table of real paths. This has huge penaltiy when hash needs to be expanded and the key gets stored in full as a path.

The second would be a radix/trie tree to do the same. Since it's a tree structure a prefix node would share structure and there is no need to rehash. It will be O(n) to search/insert where n is number of /'s in the path.

There are more options but personally I would have started with the simplest implementation first to see how well it performed and perhaps used a large initial hash size.

Comment: I don't know if I can get the "real path".  There are some Windows APIs for that kind of functionality, but I don't know if I can trust them.  As I said, I don't have access to a reproduction so I can't exactly test it.

Comment: @Luke: all you need to do is remove your test for reparse points, and set up a circular symbolic link.  That won't tell you what's going on on the original systems, but it will let you test your mitigation strategy.  Note that `GetFileInformationByHandle` gives you enough information to detect a loop, but it may be too expensive.